# Getting "The previous operation has not been completed yet." exception if using PXLongOperation within an action that is called via Contract Soap APIs

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom process that needs to happen at the time of an invoice being released. Being this process calls out to a web service I need to wrap that code in a PXLongOperation per an Acumatica best practice. if I wrap the PXLongOperation in a try/finally block things work fine relative to the UI but if I run an integration test that executed the action item calling the PXLongOperation I now get the "The previous operation has not been completed yet." error. where these passed fine before adding the long operation.

Thanks for your help

```
        [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        //IEnumerable returnValue = null;

        try
        {



            ARInvoice invoice = Base.Document.Current;
            CtpARInvoiceExt invoiceExt = PXCache<ARInvoice>.GetExtension<CtpARInvoiceExt>(invoice);

            if (invoice.DocType == "CRM")
            {
                PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, () => { ProcessClickToPayCreditMemoInvoice(invoice, invoiceExt); });
            }

            return baseMethod(new PXAdapter(Base.CurrentDocument));
        }
        //todo: I did find that this is raising an error behind the scenes but if this is commented out 
        //      everything works as expected.
        //      I have found that even if this gets commented out the the integration tests that are using
        //      The Contract Bases Soap API are failing indicating that the process has not completed.
        //catch (Exception e)
        //{
        //    //todo: this is throwing an exception with message: The previous operation has not been completed yet.
        //    throw new PXException(e,CtpMessages.ClickToPayReleaseOverrideFailed, e.Message);
        //}
        finally
        {
            //... exit logic 
        }

    }
```

The call that fails with the Contract Soap API is

```
InvokeResult invokeResult = SoapClient.Invoke(invoice, new ReleaseInvoice());
```

Answer (score 1):

This design pattern can be used to force your method to wait until the long operation is completed.

```
TimeSpan timespan;
Exception ex;
while (PXLongOperation.GetStatus(docgraph.UID, out timespan, out ex) == PXLongRunStatus.InProcess)
{ }

    // should be finished now
    // return baseMethod...
```

Comment: You could also use PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(UID) where UID is the id of the graph running the process (Ex: this.UID or Base.UID  or myGraphInstance.UID)

Comment: If you want the wait to only occur during an API call you can wrap the wait in an if for Base.IsImport or Base.IsContractAPI or something simlar.